# How to output query results to CSV file using spool command in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, spool

I am trying to output the results of a SQL query to a CSV file using the SPOOL command in Oracle SQL Developer.

I am able to output the results of a trivial query by calling it as a script. Here is the query that worked:

```
spool trivial_output.csv
select /*csv*/ * from trivial_table;
spool off;
```

And this is how I successfully called it (F5):

```
@'C:\Spool to CSV\trivial_query.sql'
```

However, when I attempt the exact same thing with a slightly more complex query, I get the error message:
"SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended 00933. 00000 -  SQL command not properly ended"

```
spool total_records.csv
select  /*csv*/     enrol.year, enrol.college, count(*) as "Total Records"
from        enrolment enrol
inner join  regis_status_type regstatus
on          enrol.regis_status_type_id = regstatus.regis_status_type_id
where       enrol.year in ('201213', '201314')
and         regstatus.regis_status_type_code in ('10','41')
group by    enrol.year, enrol.college
order by    enrol.year, enrol.college
spool off;
```

Comment: You probably need some hard coded commas in your select clause.  In fact, may as well do it properly and have some hard coded double quotes as well in case any of the colleges contain a comma.

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but the Oracle error message says the error is triggered just before the final line ("spool off"). So the problem seems to occur later than the SELECT statement.

Comment: It appears that you are missing the semicolon after your `SELECT` statement in the second example.  That causes Oracle to interpret the `spool off` as the last line of your SQL statement rather than as a separate SQL*Plus command.  That, in turn, causes your SQL statement to be syntactically invalid.

Comment: Thanks, @justin-cave. Are you saying that there should be a semicolon after the ORDER BY clause? I will try your suggestion on Monday when I am at work.

Comment: You're right... I needed to add a semi-colon after the ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just needed to add a semi-colon to separate the SQL*Plus command from the SQL statement. Thanks to [Justin Cave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10397/justin-cave)

```
spool total_records.csv
select  /*csv*/     enrol.year, enrol.college, count(*) as "Total Records"
from        enrolment enrol
inner join  regis_status_type regstatus
on          enrol.regis_status_type_id = regstatus.regis_status_type_id
where       enrol.year in ('201213', '201314')
and         regstatus.regis_status_type_code in ('10','41')
group by    enrol.year, enrol.college
order by    enrol.year, enrol.college;
spool off;
```

Answer (score -1):

```sql
spool "D:\test\test.txt"  

select  
    a.ename  
from  
    employee a  
inner join department b  
on  
(  
    a.dept_id = b.dept_id  
)  
;  
spool off
```

This query will spool the sql result here D:\test\test.txt