# How to export the result of a query in Oracle SQL to a .csv file?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, export-to-csv

I have a problem when I try to export the result of a query in SQL to a .csv file. When I try to execute the following query in SQL, it only exports an empty .csv file. In other words, it creates a file called "saldos.csv" with no information, with a size of 0 KB.

```
spool 'mypath\saldos.csv'

select *
from table;

spool off;
```

It's worth noting that the 'select * from table' query generates a valid result. If I manually export the table result, there are no issues. However, I will need to repeat this process many times, so I need to do it with code.

When running the query in SQL Developer, two tabs appear. In one tab, named 'Script Output,' I can see 'Query Run In: Result of the Query' and the final result in another tab named 'Query Result. There are no issues or error.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a duplicate question. Check out [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26431218/7989135) that the user answers themselves